# Issue with firebase-google authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know this sounds like a repeated question but I have tried all the solutions I could find here. The problem is I am not able to log in using google-firebase process in my android app. I am keep getting `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:` error.
I have also tried the process after regenerating the SHA1 key from the android studio. I have done following until now

I have followed step by step procedure of Google Sign in Auth firebase docs.
I have generated my debug SHA1 fingerprint using default android key store.
I have created OAuth 2.0 client ID in Google API console, both the android client id and the web client and while sending the request, I am using the web client id as instructed in the guide.
When this did not work I have regenerated the signing key in the android studio, Build->"Generate Signed APK" using debug. And repeated the whole process.

Yet no luck. 
Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

**Answer:-**

Here the issue was I had already used the SHA1 hash before for a different app **using a different google account**. And I was able to solve it by deleting the default debug.keystore file in the SDK folder which led the android studio to create a new keystore file with a new key. I created a new Google project in Google API console and used the new key hash for its credentials. Then I cleaned and rebuild the project inside studio after uninstalling the previous app from the emulator. And voila everything worked like a charm.
Thanks anyway for your suggestions!

Comment: And which is message error appear in DEBUG/LOGCAT? Are using genymotion?  Installed google services in your emulator?

Comment: Here is the log I could get in logcat

6437-6437/com.rss.feedster.rssfeedster D/ABD: 10 10:  null
                                                                 com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
                                                                     at
And I am using the default emulator from the Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: Check if libraries in grade are all in same lastest versions. (this logcat informations are useless) https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'

                                                                                                         Yes I have same version for all libs

Comment: I think the issue is I am using my debugkey for another project in google API console.